# Difference between react and API Endpoint

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to react; just learning it. From what I understand react gives you ability to render data more dynamically. But couldn't this be achieved using flask rest api endpoints? Kind of making AJAX calls and rendering it's response dynamically? 
What's the difference?

I'm currently trying to develop a full stack application. Trying to choose what I should use for frontend, typically on a normal day I tend to use pure HTML/CS/JS to accomplish most of my front-end task without having to use JS libraries such as react to render data dynamically, I want to improve my ways around handling front-end stuff hence wanted to learn more about react and how it can benefit me; before actually diving in it.

What can help is; if someone can lay it out for me; describing work scenario using reactjs and how I can be benefiting from using the js library.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

***In my opinion***, React is all about how effectively you can render your dom elements.

Rendering DOM (Painting your webpage with your HTML elements) is considered to be one of the costliest operation. And if you consider using other libraries( apart from react), there is a chance that your HTML will be rendered even if it doesnt change.

Here comes the power of React. React uses the concept of Virtual DOM which helps in rendering HTML to browser only when there is a change. For example, if you have a list of items being displayed, and if one list item changed because of some action, React will trigger a change to render only that element(of course we write very minimal code for this).

So if you use React as your front end library, you can easily benefit fast rendering of HTML and stopping unnecessary rendering of your DOM

Comment: " if you have a list of items being displayed, and if one list item changed because of some action, React will trigger a change to render only that element(of course we write very minimal code for this)."

Couldn't you also make an AJAX request and change specific element with the new updated data from ajax response, or how is it different from what you're saying.

Comment: 'well if its just a list item, yes, we can manage updating only that specific element. But what if you are trying to get the entire list and bind it? you probably would get the unordered/ordered list id, iterate through your data, add list items and bind them. Here irrespective of whether data changed or not you are re-rendering it. React handles it in a better way by making use of Virtual DOM effectively. Agreed. This is not a great example. But it is a notable one